# CSS element group operator?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to find out if element grouping exists in CSS. Let's say I have following code:

```
.user-form .group-area .test, .user-form .group-area .test2{}
```

Is there any way to group .test and .test2 and do something like this:

```
.user-form .group-area (.test .test2){}
```

This means that same style will apply for both .test and .test2 elements without needing to repeat .user-form .group-area second time.

Comment: We need to find a canonical question for this so long as it gets asked at least once a week...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this--> http://lesscss.org/#synopsis

Comment: Thanks, I know about less, but I don't need it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In browsers that [support the level 3 selectors](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t31), you can use the [substring matching attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings)

```
.user-form .group-area *[class^="test"]
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yh9Fw/1/

Comment: Spaces are explicitly forbidden in the `[~=]` attribute selector. Your second selector doesn't do exactly what is intended, and will break if there's another class that doesn't start with `test` and comes first.

Comment: @BoltClock: from the spec: "Represents an element with the att attribute whose value is a white space-separated list of words, one of which is exactly "val". If "val" contains white space, it will never represent anything (since the words are separated by spaces). If "val" is the empty string, it will never represent anything either."

Comment: From what you just quoted: "If 'val' contains white space, it will never represent anything." The selector checks for words that are separated by spaces, so you can't check for space characters because those are being used as separators and thus cannot occur in the words themselves. Or to put it another way, `[~=]` can only check one class at a time.

Comment: @BoltClock you are correct, I read the spec wrong. Fixed now, with fiddle. BTW, no longer a unicorn? ;-)

Comment: Still am... [on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/137537/boltclocks-a-unicorn) ;)

Comment: Well this is not what I really want. Just to be more clear instead of .test and .test2 classes use input & select types
I think there might not be possible to do it with css at all :/